# how to continue in a python script, if the program exits/crashes with pwntools?

Tags: python-2.7, pwntools

I want to continue the python script do things, when the program crashes/exits. But it does not work. For example:

```
from pwn import *

p = process("./proc")

p.interactive()
<do stuff and exit>

print("Some stuff")
```

But when the progam `proc` exits/crashes, the part below `p.interactive()` is not executed. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a "try except" which allows you to run code in the try part, and once the program crashes it moves on to the except. read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp).

an example:

```
try:
  print(x)
except NameError:
  print("Variable x is not defined")
except:
  print("Something else went wrong")
```